# Azure service fabric on-premises licensing

Tags: azure-service-fabric

What is the licensing story with on-premises SF deployment?

Will it included with a Windows Server license?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about licensing and not programming as defined in the [help] guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

The Service Fabric standalone installer for Windows Server is currently in preview and thus not supported for production deployments. At this point, there is no plan to charge a license fee for the installer when it GAs but that is subject to change.